# How does google analytics avoid same origin policy?

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics, same-origin-policy

I had an idea for a project involving a Javascript terminal utilising a specified PHP script as a server to carry out remote functions. I understand that the same origin policy would be an obstacle with such a project, but looking at google analytics, which I use every day, it seems they have a way of avoiding the problem on a huge scale.

Comment: In general, `script` tag & jsonp format, sometimes `iframe` is used.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning jsonp, I was not aware of this complement. I always wondered why google don't separate JS and HTML, it seems the `script` tag is crucial for this.

Comment: From what i remember, GA inserts (via JS) an `<img>` with the src attribute containing all the info GA servers need to know (there is no cross-domain restriction on embedding images). The actual image returned i believe is a 1x1 blank image.

Comment: Define JavaScript terminal.

Comment: @techfoodbar interesting yet very hacky. I would expect the `script` tag to be enough. According to wikipedia some use JS injection to create multiple `script` tags.

Comment: granted it's WIP and the functionality is limited and rudimentary but with the use of xmlhttprequest could be extended to do much more, especially if it could provide remote connections to other domains.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Google Analytics, Google AdWords and practically all other analytics/web-marketing platforms use `<img>` tags.

They load their JS programs, those programs handle whatever tracking you put on the page, then they create an image and set the source of the image to be equal to whatever their server's domain is, plus add all of your tracking information to the query string.

The crux is that it doesn't matter how it gets there:
the server is only concerned about the data which is inside of the URL being called, and the client is only concerned about making a call to a specific URL, and not in getting any return value.
Thus, somebody chose `<img>` years and years ago, and companies have been using it ever since.

Comment: @Lee It is. But web-analytics tracking and search engine marketing have been around, in one form or another, since before AJAX became a household name, and everybody was still wrapping scripts in `CDATA` comment tags. Back then, the `img` tag was probably chosen because of the `noscript` benefit. In fact, if you look at AdWords tracking, or even SiteCatalyst (a program you might pay $60,000+/year for) tracking, they've still got a `noscript` section below their JS section. So the JS will load external programs and build an image to be similar to the `noscript` version.

Comment: @Lee despite being a hack, doing it the correct way would leave large holes in your data (even larger than the ones using this flimsy method provides), because many browsers don't support CORS. In another 5 years, this may be a viable solution, because every man, woman and toaster will be infused with cross-origin JS. Until then, we're stuck with sub-optimal solutions for maximizing the number of people who are tracked, which comes down to an `<img>` or a `<script>` which is intended to be 100% void of content.

Comment: I understand, I expect it works well as time has shown. The old "if it aint broke, don't fix it" adage comes to mind.

Comment: But what if someone sends a curl request to the analytics servers with the origin set as xyz.com. How would analytics identify if this is a valid request or a bot.

Answer (score 15):

The modern way to allow cross-domain requests is for the server to respond with the following header to any requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This allows requests from any hosts, or alternatively a specific host can be used instead of `*`.  This is called Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).  Unfortunately it's not supported in older browsers, so you need hacks to work around the browser in that case (like a commenter said perhaps by requesting an image).

Comment: This seems like a much "cleaner" way. Good input

Comment: downside is you wont be able to send or read cookies ? Cookies are important to track the user - even when he's not logged in

Answer (score -1):

You can get codes from third-party sites, but collecting data with them is restricted by [the policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Google collects data with "_gaq" function array embedded by the 1st-orgine-site, and then Google sends the collected data as they are embedded in the http-request parameters.

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=4&utmn=769876874&utmhn=example.com&utmcs=ISO-8859-1&utmsr=1280x1024&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=1&utmfl=9.0%20%20r115&utmcn=1&utmdt=GATC012%20setting%20variables&utmhid=2059107202&utmr=0&utmp=/auto/GATC012.html?utm_source=www.gatc012.org&utm_campaign=campaign+gatc012&utm_term=keywords+gatc012&utm_content=content+gatc012&utm_medium=medium+gatc012&utmac=UA-30138-1&utmcc=__utma%3D97315849.1774621898.1207701397.1207701397.1207701397.1%3B...
```

Google demonstrates clearly [how tracking works.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview)